# SPARQL: How do I List and count each data type in an RDF dataset?

Tags: types, count, sparql

I am trying to count the instances of each datatype in a dataset. It is a simple dataset with only three data types: integer, string and dateTime.

I can get the number of datatypes (3) by querying:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT datatype(?o)) 
AS ?dTypeCount) {?s ?p ?o. FILTER (isLiteral(?o)) } 
GROUP BY ?dTypeCount
```

result like so:
    --------------
    | dTypeCount |
    ==============
    | 3          |
    --------------

I can get the listing of the datatypes (string, integer, dateTime) by querying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (datatype(?o) AS ?dType) 
{?s ?p ?o. FILTER (isLiteral(?o)) }
```

result like so:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| dType                                       |
===============================================
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> |
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>   |
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I can get a count of each datatype by querying:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?o) AS ?dTypeCount) 
{?s ?p ?o. FILTER (isLiteral(?o)) } 
GROUP BY datatype(?o)
```

result like so:

```
--------------
| dTypeCount |
==============
| 23494      |
| 93548      |
| 228942     |
--------------
```

but I cannot get the name of the datatype displayed beside it's count i.e. looking something like so:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| dType                                       || dTypeCount |
=============================================================
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> || 23494      |
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>   || 93548      |
| <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>  || 228942     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried various combinations of sub-queries, UNIONs, multiple GROUP BY bound variable and either do not get the desired result 
or get a "Non-group key variable in SELECT: " error. All help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've grouped by the datatype of ?o, you know that all the ?o values in a group have the same datatype.  You can just **sample** that to get one of those values, and then take the datatype of it:

```sql
select (datatype(sample(?o)) as ?datatype)
       (count(?o) AS ?dTypeCount)
where {
  ?s ?p ?o
  filter isLiteral(?o)
} 
group by datatype(?o)
```

If you don't like having quite so many complex expressions around, you could **bind** the datatype within the query:

```sql
select ?datatype (count(?o) AS ?dTypeCount)
where {
  ?s ?p ?o
  filter isLiteral(?o)
  bind (datatype(?o) as ?datatype)
} 
group by ?datatype
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, the second of your solutions performs fastest of all three so I am going to go with it.

Comment: @Hilary The second might be faster because of (depending on how the query engine is implemented) fewer calls to functions (e.g., there's just one call to datatype instead of two), so it's not a huge surprise that it's faster.  (But I didn't time them beforehand, either.)

Comment: Good to know, thanks Joshua. Still learning every day. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

```
SELECT (COUNT(?o) AS ?dTypeCount) (MAX(?datatype) AS ?dtype)
{?s ?p ?o. 
 BIND (datatype(?o) AS ?datatype) 
FILTER (isLiteral(?o)) } 
GROUP BY datatype(?o)
```

As you have already grouped by datatype you just need a group function to reference it.

Comment: Why `MAX(?datatype) AS ?dtype`? That implies an ordering amongst a bunch of values that should be the same.  `sample` would probably be more appropriate as an aggregate function.  I.e,. `select (count(?o) as ?dTypeCount) (sample(?datatype) as ?dtype) { ... }`.  And since you're already binding datatype(?o) as  ?datatype, you can `group by ?datatype`, which might avoid an extra function call.

Comment: You're right, your way is likely to be more efficient. MAX rather than sample is probably just my SQL background showing through.